# Remove similar sentences in a list

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

Let's say I have a file with data like name, phone, birthday and some lines come with and without (partially) those data:

```
John || <missing_bday> || 92475123
```

I'm trying to write a script which would choose between these lines using phone number as a mark because it's a obligatory field and unique (in the list) and all lines have it, then if the `len()` of one is bigger than the other I would append it to a new list. How would I do that? I've parsed those lines to a list and I thought about using some loops, the index of each item in the list and comparing with the other but the name length varies. this is just a example, the real lines have some trash numbers as acc date created, hour in the end, `endswith()` woulnd't work.

```
list = ["|| 19 || 99210831 ", "John || 19 || 83291234", "Angelica |||| 99210831", "|||| 99210831"
newlist = []
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Please try to elaborate, and also show sample input _and_ output, as well as any code you have written and attempts you have made to solve this.

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking. What should the output of this sequence be with such a script.

Comment: Sorry about it. Look the "list", there're several items and some come with or without information as name, age but never without phone number so I want to append the item which bigger len() based on the phone number. Look at the two first items of the list "Jonh || 19 || 83291234" and "|| 19 || 99210831 ", the first one len() is bigger than the second and also you can see that they have the same phone number, so I'd like to append it. @Cyphase

Comment: @Milbol, those are not the same phone numbers. And again, please include sample output.

Comment: @Cyphase ops, "Angelica |||| 99210831" and "|| 19 || 99210831 ". I don't have any output, as I said, I tried but failed. There was a response about using endswith but this a example, the real lines have numbers trash in the end of it as hour of acc creation. So what I need is just to compare those items (the ones with the same phone number)  in the list and append it the one with the biggest len()

Comment: Why don't you want to merge Angelica's name and age into one record with her phone number, instead of just taking her name and ignoring her age?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler In this example would fit but the real scenario doesn't because there is "angel", "angelica", "ageglica" and all with the same phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runs through each line and gets the data, then builds a dictionary.

This means it can combine the longest name, and oldest age, for each phone number, over many records. Then print them all out at the end.

```
data_in = ["|| 19 || 99210831 ", "John || 19 || 83291234", "Angelica |||| 99210831", "|||| 99210831"]

data = {}


for line in data_in:
    line_parts = line.replace(' ','').split('||')
    name_in, age_in, tel_in = line_parts[:3]

    saved_name, saved_age = data.get(tel_in, ('',0))

    if len(name_in) > len(saved_name):
        saved_name = name_in

    if age_in > saved_age:
        saved_age = age_in

    data[tel_in] = (saved_name, saved_age)


for tel, (name, age) in data.items():
    print '||'.join((name, age, tel))
```

NB. naming your list `list` is a bad habit, because that name already means something else in Python. (It's the builtin `list()` function)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? You can modify how you want to print it out in the end.

```py
import re

lines = ['|| 19 || 99210831 ',
         'John || 19 || 83291234',
         'Angelica |||| 99210831',
         '|||| 99210831']

directory = {}

for line in lines:
  fields = re.split("\s*\|\|\s*", line)
  phone = fields[2].split()[0] # Get phone number only

  if phone not in directory:
    directory[phone] = []

  directory[phone].append(line)

for phone, records in directory.iteritems():
  print "Records for phone: " + phone
  for record in records:
    print "    " + record
  print
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = sorted(open("file.dat"),key=lamda x:x.rsplit("|",1)[-1])
g = itertools.groupby(lines,lambda line:line.rsplit("|",1)[-1])
for key,result in g:
    print max(g,key=lambda x:len(filter(None,line.split("|")))
```

first this groups all the entries that have the same end
then this selects the best ... the best being defined as having the most values

Comment: damm, sorry, too hard for me yet! here's a response to other user: "Angelica |||| 99210831" and "|| 19 || 99210831 ". I don't have any output, as I said, I tried but failed. There was a response about using endswith but this a example, the real lines have numbers trash in the end of it as hour of acc creation. So what I need is just to compare those items (the ones with the same phone number) in the list and append it the one with the biggest len() – If you get it and is possible to simplify your code, I'd love else I try to understand it anyway!

Comment: its hard ... but i think this does it ... so you are saying the phonen number isnt the last item(even though it is in your example?)